# All Possible k combinations of list with size n

Tags: java, arrays, list, combinations

I am trying to get all possible combinations of size K from a list of size N.

I have a List that takes "Human" objects and I am trying to create a new ArrayList which will be filled with List objects. Each of the Lists will be a different combination of "Human" objects.

A simple example with numbers would be: From a list consisting 1,2,3 I want to get an ArrayList which looks like this: `[[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]`
I also wouldn't mind if it looks like this: `[[1], [2], [3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]`

Here is my code:

```
public void combination(List<Human> people, int k, ArrayList<List> result) {
    if (people.size() < k) {
        return;
    }
    if (k == 1) {
        for (Human hum : people) {
            List<Human> combinations = new ArrayList<Human>();
            combinations.add(hum);
            result.add(combinations);
        }
    }
    else if (people.size() == k) {
        List<Human> combinations = new ArrayList<Human>();
        for (Human hum : people) {
            combinations.add(hum);
        }
       result.add(combinations);
    }
    else if (people.size() > k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
            List<Human> combinations = new ArrayList<Human>();
            combinations.add(people.get(i));
            result.add(combinations);
            combination(people.subList(i + 1, people.size()), k - 1, result);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the last method in this site as a reference: https://hmkcode.com/calculate-find-all-possible-combinations-of-an-array-using-java/

At the moment I get the correct number of results in my new ArrayList but each List inside only consist of a single Human.

I highly suspect the problem lies in the last `else if` because I have hard time understanding the recursion.

Please feel free to ask any questions or suggest any other implementation for this.

Comment: Everything but the else if is just code to quickly skip the last `for` loop. In the last `for` loop a combination is created for each human, and only that one human is added, so of course every combination only has one human in it. I presume every human in the list is unique?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks for the reply, that's what I thought, however I can't get my head around how to modify the "result" in order to get what I need

Comment: Maybe you missed the question in my comment? No dupes in the list?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yes sorry, every human in the list is unique and yes there are no dupes

Comment: Isn't this already happening in the last loop where I call it recursively with a smaller 'k' and a smaller list of People?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210942/discussion-between-maarten-bodewes-and-teodor-narliyski).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your loop, you are calling `combination` function only on continuous sublists (for instance if the initial set is [1,2,3,4,5], you are not calling the function on sublist of [1,3,5]).

Also, keep in mind you should override the `equals` function in your `Human` class.

```
    private void subsetsOf(List<Human> humans, int k, int index, Set<Human> tempSet, List<Set<Human>> finalSet) {
    if (tempSet.size() == k) {
        finalSet.add(new HashSet<>(tempSet));
        return;
    }

    if (index == humans.size())
        return;


    Human human = humans.get(index);

    tempSet.add(human);
    subsetsOf(humans, k, index+1, tempSet, finalSet);

    tempSet.remove(human);
    subsetsOf(humans, k, index+1, tempSet, finalSet);
}

public List<Set<Human>> combination(List<Human> humans, int k) {
    List<Set<Human>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    subsetsOf(humans, k, 0, new HashSet<Human>(), result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Very elegant solution, should be optimal as well I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another implementation that never removes anything nor creates spurious lists of anything. It only ever adds when it needs to, no `equals` necessary for `T`, as long as they are unique by themselves.

Just for the learning experience, right out of the top of my head:

```
package com.stackexchange.so;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RecursiveCombinationCreator {
    /**
     * Creates combinations of elements of a specific combination size.
     * 
     * @param <T>             the type of the elements
     * @param elts            a list of elements, which should be unique
     * @param combinationSize the size of the combinations
     * @return a list of combinations
     */
    public static <T> List<List<T>> createCombinations(List<T> elts, int combinationSize) {
        var fullCombinations = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
        createCombinations(elts, fullCombinations, new ArrayList<T>(), 0, combinationSize);
        return fullCombinations;
    }

    /**
     * Recursive function that grows the combination size, and adds full combinations when the combination size is met.
     * To avoid duplicates, only elements that are higher in the list are added to the combination. The combination is
     * complete when <code>missing == 0</code>.
     * 
     * @param <T>              the type of the elements
     * @param elts             the elements to create combinations from, all elements should be unique
     * @param fullCombinations the final result array of the combinations, shared among all recursive calls
     * @param combination      the current combination that needs to get <code>missing<code> members
     * @param index            the index of the element one higher than the last element in the combination
     * @param missing          the amount of elements needed to complete the combination
     */
    private static <T> void createCombinations(List<T> elts, List<List<T>> fullCombinations, List<T> combination,
            int index, int missing) {
        if (missing == 0) {
            fullCombinations.add(combination);
            return;
        }

        // we don't need to go over elts.size() - missing because then the combination cannot be completed, too few left
        for (int i = index; i <= elts.size() - missing; i++) {
            List<T> newCombination;
            if (i == elts.size() - missing) {
                // optimization: avoid dereferencing the final combination, reuse
                newCombination = combination;
            } else {
                newCombination = new ArrayList<T>(combination);
            }
            newCombination.add(elts.get(i));
            createCombinations(elts, fullCombinations, newCombination, i + 1, missing - 1);
        }
    }

    // === TEST CODE ===

    // we needed humans, OK
    private static class Human {
        private int id;

        public Human(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Integer.toString(id);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // generate input
        var humans = new ArrayList<Human>();
        for (int id = 0; id < 200; id++) {
            var human = new Human(id);
            humans.add(human);
        }

        // just that one call
        var fullcombinations = createCombinations(humans, 199);

        // show output
        System.out.println(fullcombinations.size());
        for (List<Human> combination : fullcombinations) {
            System.out.println(combination);
        }
    }
}
```

Note too that the maximum depth is equal to `k` (or `k + 1`), which means that your stack is safe from too many recursive calls.

Comment: I guess that using an ordered set should also be possible, but that requires some rethinking.